# Problem with google chrome ?

Tags: html, google-chrome

```
<fieldset style="background-color:#5959DE">
<span> <a href="page2.html"> <strong> Profile </strong> </a> </span>
<span class="profilee"> <a href="page2.html"> <strong> Friends  </strong> </a> </span>
<span class="profilee"> <a href="page2.html"> <strong> Pictures </strong> </a> </span>
<span class="profilee"> <a href="page2.html"> <strong> Updates  </strong> </a> </span>
<span class="profilee"> <a href="page2.html"> <strong> Messages </strong> </a> </span>
<span class="profilee"><a href="page2.html"> <strong>  Find     </strong> </a> </span> 
<input type=text size="20"/>
<span style="padding-left:2%"> <a href="page2.html"> <strong> Privacy</strong> </a>     </span>
<span class="profilee"> <a href="page2.html"> <strong> Availability</strong> </a> </span>
<span class="privacy"> <a href="page2.html"> <strong> Sign Off </strong> </a> </span>
</fieldset>
```

The Problem Im facing is its working fine in mozzilla and iE but in google chrome the sign off is jumping to next line.

I have used

```
width:100%; width:100px; <!-- I mean I used % and px and em but none working-->
```

But still its not working. Why its jumping to next line in google chrome? How can i put it on one line even on google chrome?

Comment: works fine for me in chrome 13 http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Ben: http://jsfiddle.net/8nJe7/ ftfy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update you question with some more details. How does the wrapper element look like? What properties does all classes have (`class="privacy"` etc). Also where have you tested the `width:100%; width:100px;` ?

I would guess that the problem is with the wrapper elements width, since all elements you have (`span, a, strong, input`) are [inline elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3). This means that all elements will behave as normal text in a document, fills one line until it's full then continues onto the next. This is if you haven't specified anything else in you css.

Could you provide a screenshoot?

Try increasing the width of the `fieldset`(maybe like 350px).

One last note. The `fieldset` element is to be used for defining set's of a form. Not to a menu, have a [look here](http://htmldog.com/guides/htmladvanced/forms/).